# Java: How to pass Point values to a Polyline?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, polyline

So I have this `Polyline` class that uses another class (`Point`) to create a polyline.

The class `Point` just defines a point with a x and y value and a name to it (Point A, Point B, etc)

```
public class Polyline 

{
private Point []    corner;

public Polyline ()
{
    this.corner = new Point[0];

}

public Polyline (Point [] corner)
{
    this.corner = new Point [cornerlength];
    for (int i = 0; i < corner.length; i++)
        this.corner[i] = new Point (corner[i]);

}
```

Now my question is, how do I give these corners their values? I made a programme called `PolylineTest` and I would like to give it some values and print it out, but I haven't managed to figure out how to do it.

I figured it would be something like this:

```
Polyline [] p1 = new Polyline[0];
```

but I can't figure out how to give it a value.

Could anyone give me a nudge to the right direction?

Thank you in advance

(the code currently does not compile)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: I tried Polylinje [] p1 = new Polylinje [0];
  p1 [0] = {" Point A", 3, 4};
but it says array constanst can only be used as initializers

Comment: Yes, which makes absolutely no sense. Highly recommend reading the docs / tutorial.

Comment: Also read the part of the tutorial about classes and constructors. A Point is not an array.

Comment: Among other problems. Perhaps starting with a beginner's book on Java would be a better route than typing random things into a computer and expecting them to do something.

Answer (score 1):

Asuming your `Point` class looks something like:

```
public class Point {

    public String name;
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(String name, int x, int y) {
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point(Point p) {
        this.name = p.name;
        this.x = p.x;
        this.y = p.y;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + "[" + x + ", " + y + "]";
    }
}
```

and you add this method to your `Polyline` class:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Polyline " + Arrays.toString(corner);
}
```

the usage looks like:

```
public class PolylineTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point[] points = new Point[] {
                new Point("A", 4, 2),
                new Point("B", 8, 5),
                new Point("C", 1, 7)
        };
        Polyline polyline = new Polyline(points);
        System.out.println(polyline);
    }
}
```